# Rsync daemon not succesfully starting on boot

Tags: raspbian, samba

Rsync server was working successfully on my RPi B+ until today. I've upgraded the attached USB from 32 GB to 64 GB (both USB 3.0). Then I got reckless and changed a bunch of settings for the Samba Rsync server too. Now it does work if I manually start the daemon by running

```
sudo rsync --daemon
```

But not when booting the RPi. When I set RSYNC_ENABLE to true in `/etc/default/rsync`, nothing is logged in `/var/log/rsyncd.log` when booting, so I assume it is not running. When I set `RSYNC_ENABLE` to `inetd` I see the following error in the log

```
error [720] rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c ..
```

I occasionally get this error when starting the daemon manually. I suspect this error to be caused by the fact that the USB is not yet ready. When the daemon is successfully running, I can see the backup module from another computer, so that should rule out many possible problems I assume.

So, overall a lot of assuming and fiddling around. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding the line `@reboot rsync --daemon` to crontab (`sudo crontab -e`).

The error was caused by a full file system. I thought that I was writing to an USB when writing to /mnt/cruzer, but the USB was not mounted at start. So I was actually writing to the SD card. I could have saved myself a lot of trouble if I checked `df` more often. This lists the used file systems and space.

Comment: Chuckling... wouldn't be the first time I've written behind a failed mount before...